# What is the shortcut to auto import library in visual studio 2010, 2012 (if any- like Alt+Enter in Netbeans)?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I don't know where is the short-cut button to auto generate namespace import in C# winform/ window store... application, like the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut in NetBean IDE. I and some of my friends have programmed in visual studio for several years but when we need to import library, we have to move the cursor after the Class code and click to show namespace like this:

[image: missing reference error]

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to open up the quick fix which will give you different options to fix such an error, including adding usings for the correct namespace—if VS finds a valid type in the references.

Comment: Thank you about your great advise :). Now I feel very comfortable :). I also try to use Resharper plugin to code easier

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl+R and Ctrl+G** ... OR **Ctrl + R + G**

[image]

Another little option through the toolbar.

[image: An option through the toolbar]