# Is there a possibility that Visual Studio will show propositions how to fix an error [like in Eclipse]?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Just like in title.
In Eclipse (coding Java) if I forget some import or make a typo, IDE gives me few possible solutions (after hover mistake) e.g. `import ClassYouForgotten` or `Did you mean System` when I typed "Sytsem" or something like that.

Now, when I'm coding C# in Visual Studio I get only an information that I made a mistake - no possible solutions, just deal with it.

Is there a possibility that Visual Studio will show propositions how to fix an error?
*I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 if it matters.

Comment: Searching for tools/tutorials is generally off-topic... Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229519/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-library-in-visual-studio-2010-2012-if-any, if it is not enough - buy R#

Comment: Yes, but it's not free. Check out ReSharper.

Answer (score 2):

If you type the class name correctly (case-sensitive) and you have the correct reference, after you wrote the class name, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.
Then a little menu will popup under the class name and suggest you to add it namespace as `using`.

[image]

Visual studio can not help you if:

1. You wrote wrong class name.
2. Or You haven't added the correct reference.

Then you need to deal with the problem by browse the namespace in the code by yourself.

Any time you can use the `Object Browser` window, to browse in the assemblies that in you solution.